# Total sales per month

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

If you have a table with `SALES {Customer_ID, Price, SmallDateTime date}`.  How do you report all sales per month?

```
SELECT Sum(Price) As Total Sales FROM SALES Group By What Having What
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
  SELECT YEAR(date) as SalesYear,
         MONTH(date) as SalesMonth,
         SUM(Price) AS TotalSales
    FROM Sales
GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
ORDER BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(7), SmallDateTime, 120) as Year_Month,
       SUM(Price)
    FROM Sales
    GROUP BY CONVERT(CHAR(7), SmallDateTime, 120) 
    ORDER BY Year_Month
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to calculate the first day of the month

```
Select DateAdd(d,DateDiff(d,0,[Date])-DatePart(d,[Date])+1,0)
    , Sum( Price )
From Sales
Group By DateAdd(d,DateDiff(d,0,[Date])-DatePart(d,[Date])+1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT A.CAL_YEAR AS YEAR  ,A.CAL_WEEK AS WEEK,SUM(B.SUM_OF_PROFIT) as profit FROM
CALANDER A,SALES_FACT B WHERE A.DATE_ID=B.DATE_ID
GROUP BY A.CAL_YEAR,A.CAL_WEEK;
```