# SQL how to sum quantity monthly for report

Tags: sql

I have table like this

```
PartID   Quantity     Date
12315       1      2017-01-24
51245       3      2017-01-26
12345       4      2017-02-20
12415       1      2017-02-25
.....     ..     ...........
```

I need for the report result like:

```
Monthly Quantity January: 4
Monthly Quantity February: 5
```

So in my report - every column should have the name of month and include all quantities (count) for this month. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A similar question was answered below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5984765/6158987

Comment: You need to tag your question with the RDBMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options you can have :

1) create another column and store name of month in it .

```
PartID Quantity     Date.        Month
12315     1      2017-01-24.    January
51245     3      2017-01-26.    January
12345     4      2017-02-20.    February
12415     1      2017-02-25.    February
```

And use below query to get the report as you needed :

```
Select sum(Quantity) as total_quantity, Month from table group by Month
```

2) by using inbuilt date and time functions of MySQL.

```
Select sum(Quantity) as total_quantity, Month(Date) as month from table group by Month(Date)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for a query like:

```
select month(Date), sum(Quantity)
from table
group by month(Date)
```

Answer (score 1):

In MS SQL :

You can use something like this:

**DATENAME()** function returns a specified part of a given date, as a string value.

To know more about DATENAME(), please visit https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datename.asp

**CAST()** function converts an expression from one data type to another data type.

To know more about CAST(), please visit https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_cast.asp

```
SELECT
  MONTH(Date) AS MonthNo,
  'Monthly Quantity ' + DATENAME(MONTH, date) + ' : ' + CAST(SUM(Quantity) AS nvarchar(10)) AS Monthwise
FROM parttable
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, date),
         MONTH(Date)
ORDER BY MONTH(Date)
```

So the output will be

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Which database are you using?

On SQL Server:

`SELECT
DATENAME(month, Date) AS 'Month Name', SUM(Quantity)
FROM table
GROUP BY DATENAME(month, Date)`

Comment: I'm using MS SQL